# Customized Close, Restore, Minimize buttons in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm want to make customized **Close**, **Resize** and **Minimize** commands with buttons which I made with image. The C# code for closing the app is `App.Current.Shutdown();`
How is the code for minimize and resize (maximize)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;` and `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;`?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [WindowState property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;  
this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

specifically.

Comment: I'm marking the other answer as answer cuz he needs more rep, and you have more than enough :)

Answer (score 1):

For the resize command I found something that check the state of the windows and then it changes the windows size

```
if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
{
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
 }
 else
 {
     this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
 }
```

thank you guys for your help